# Create session Payment confirmation on Stripe Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I've created a POST request to collect payments from customers via Stripe

```
  let data = {
      errorMsg:'',
      key: process.env.STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY
    }
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      line_items: [
        {
          price_data: {
            currency: 'usd',
            product_data: {
              name: 'My tools',
            },
            unit_amount: 10,
          },
          quantity: 1,
        },
      ],
      mode: 'payment',
      success_url: 'https://example.com/success',
      cancel_url: 'https://example.com/cancel',
    });
    const sessiondetails = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(session.id);
    console.log("session details", sessiondetails);
    res.redirect(303, session.url);
}))
```

Can someone tell me how can I confirm that the payment is successfully processed before adding credits/allow customers to download digital products or before redirecting the user?

Answer (score 2):

The [recommended way](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders#fulfill) to track this is using the `checkout.session.completed` webhook to handle fulfillment. Either here or [retrieving the session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve) as you've done, you can check if the `payment_status` ([API ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-payment_status)) is `paid` before granting access/credits.